# Is tensorflow LKJ distribution correct?

Tags: covariance-matrix, tensorflow

I am trying to verify that this distribution is propoprtional to a power of the determinant of the matrix:

https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/CholeskyLKJ

Which is an implementation of https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X09000876

The LKJ distribution's density is supposed to be proportional to a power of the determinant. In comparing the numbers it looks off or the noise is actually much higher than I imagine.

This is what I am doing:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
ion()

dim = 50
samples = 1000

y = np.random.randn(samples, dim) * 0.010
C = np.cov(y.T)
B = tf.linalg.cholesky(C)

yy = np.random.randn(samples, dim) * 0.010
CC = np.cov(yy.T)
BB = tf.linalg.cholesky(CC)

log_det_C = tf.math.log(tf.linalg.det(C))
log_det_CC = tf.math.log(tf.linalg.det(CC))
diff_log_det = log_det_C - log_det_CC

base_c = 2.0
d = tfp.distributions.CholeskyLKJ(dimension=y.shape[1], concentration=tf.cast(base_c, tf.float64))

logp_B = d.log_prob(B)
logp_BB = d.log_prob(BB)
diff = logp_B - logp_BB
print(diff, diff_log_det, diff / diff_log_det)

a = dict()
for i in range(100):
    y = np.random.randn(samples, dim) * 0.010
    C = np.cov(y.T)
    B = tf.linalg.cholesky(C)
    log_det = tf.math.log(tf.linalg.det(C)).numpy().item()
    a[log_det] = d.log_prob(B).numpy().item()

a = pd.Series(a).sort_index()

fig = figure(1)
fig.clf()
ax = gca()
a.plot(ax=ax)
ax.grid()
ax.set_xlabel('log_det')
ax.set_ylabel('log_prob')
ax.set_title(f'concentraion = {base_c}, dim={C.shape[0]}')
fig.tight_layout()
show()
```

Am I misunderstanding something about the LKJ distribution or have a bug? It should give the same ratio each time dependening only on the concentration parameter since the normalizing constant is a shift in log space and cancels out. You are then left with $\alpha ( \log det(B) - \log det(BB) )$.

[image]

UPDATE:

It seems the noise is much less when concentration parameter is in the range of 1000. I think it is just numerical error driving the variation in results. Likely there is a reasonable choice of concentration one needs to make and that is dependent on the dimension. This makes some sense since the determinant is "extrensic" and you need a higher concentration to force the product away from zero as more dimensions come into play.

Comment: Could you phrase your question in words rather then in code? What exaltly is your question?

Comment: Added a bit, it is literlly just a question a) is the LJK prop to log determinant, b) if so why does the below plot show so much noise and c) if not why not?